# How to upload multiple image using Laravel collective form?

Tags: laravel

I want to upload multiple image using Laravel collective form, but I
don't know how to set multiple attribute when I am uploading multiple
images. The image input field is given bellow:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <label >Slider Images</label>
    <img name="sliders" id='smallLogo' src="" alt="image" class='img-responsive sliders'><br><br>
    {{-- <input multiple="multiple" name="sliders[]" type="file"> --}}
    {!! Form::file("sliders[]", null,["class"=>"form-control"]) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: would you provide code, what you wrote in your `controller`...? have your tried ?

Comment: Actually i just want to know how to write input field in laravel collective form for multiple image ..only form input field

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
if($request->hasFile('sliders'))
{
    $slider = $request->file('sliders');
    foreach ($sliders as $slider) {
        $file->store('path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i just want to know how to write input field in laravel collective form for multiple image ..only form input field

Comment: Can you paste your controller code in question please?

Comment: I didn't write controller part .After writing i will paste it .